# Django urls straight to html template

Tags: python, django

Learning django & python.

Just set up a new site after doing the tutorial. Now for arguments sake say I want to add a bunch of About us, FAQ basic html pages with very limited dynamic elements do you go ahead and write a new line in my urls.py file for each page? or is their some neat way to say map all * *.html to the relevant .html file directly?

In general even if it does require a view will I have to write a new line in the url.py file for every page?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As long as there is some uniquely identifying section in the URL, you will not need to create an entry in urls.py for each direct-template url.

For example, you could say that all urls ending in ".html" are referencing a direct file from the templates.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'(.+\.html)$', 'direct_to_template'),
    # ...
)
```

Take a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template for details.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't exactly what i needed but this did the trick.

('(.+\.html)$', direct_to_template),

Comment: Django 1.6: No module named simple

Answer (score 30):

Currently the best way to do this is using TemplateView from generic class-based views:

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

    path(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),
```

Comment: If you just want a single page to render directly as a view, with no additional context, this is the easiest way to do it!

Answer (score 12):

Write a url which grabs the static pages you're interested in

```
url(r'^(?P<page_name>about|faq|press|whatever)/$', 'myapp.staticpage', name='static-pages')
```

The `staticpage` view function in `myapp`

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.http import Http404

def staticpage(request, page_name):
    # Use some exception handling, just to be safe
    try:
        return direct_to_template(request, '%s.html' % (page_name, ))
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Of course, you need to follow a naming convention for your templates, but this pattern can be expanded upon as needed.

This is better than the `.+\.html` pattern because it will treat templates which don't exist as 404s, whereas `.+\.html` will blow up with 500 errors if the template doesn't exist.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using the [**class based views**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/) because `direct_to_template` has been [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/), you can create a simple wrapper that renders your own templates directly:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.http import Http404

class StaticView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, page, *args, **kwargs):
        self.template_name = page
        response = super(StaticView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            return response.render()
        except TemplateDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()
```

and in your router:

```
from myapp.static.views import StaticView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<page>.+\.html)$', StaticView.as_view()),
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Need `from django.http import Http404` in router (`urls.py`)

Comment: Great, is the first dot to express "many chars" and the second dot (escaped) to separate file name and html-type?

Comment: @Timo, if you asking url regex; <page>.+ means file slug (without file extension) and \.html forces that it must be an .html file for the urls and the file itself. hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to write a single custom view that wraps the `direct_to_template` generic view. The wrapper could accept a parameter and accordingly form the name of the template and pass it to `direct_to_template`. This way you can route multiple pages with a single URL configuration.

Something like this:

```
url(r'^foo/(?P<page_name>\w+).html$', 'my_static_wrapper', name = 'my_static_wrapper'),

def my_static_wrapper(request, page_name):
    # form template name and call direct_to_template
```

That said I suspect that there are better solutions out there though.

Answer (score 0):

Slight Changes for latest versions of Django.

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
 path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),
]
```