# How to automatically map url to template tree?

Tags: django, django-templates

Let's suppose that we have the following templates files layout:

```
templates/
  base.html
  about/
    company/
      history.html
```

`base.html` contains page layout and included in every other template.

And I want every url automatically uses corresponding template. 
For example, request for `http://site/about/company/history/` should  render `templates/about/company/history.html` template.
So the site is almost static except base template includes.

Is it some standard method for doing this?

As far as I know `direct_to_template` can work only with certain template.

And as next step it would be nice to put static content behind templates.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402708/django-urls-straight-to-html-template

Comment: Thanks, @ankit-jaiswal. It is duplicate. Could not find one. What about static content behind templates? Is it possible?