# Integrating Sphinx Documentation with django

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I have created sphinx documentation for a django project. It created a build folder an html folder and an index.html file. What im not to sure about is how to integrate the index.html file into my project. Is it possible to simply add it to url config and if how would it be formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the 'best' way to do this is just at the HTTP server level and not in Django itself (at least that's how I've done it in the past).  You don't need or want any pieces of Django layer to serve out your sphinx docs, you just need a 'vanilla' web server setup to do that.

Also, this could help [Django urls straight to html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402708/django-urls-straight-to-html-template) if you insist on using Django... but again, I'd vote to just setupt a /docs directory under your root and point it at the sphinx data via basic Apache/NGINX/etc config.

Comment: I have docs/ in my project root. /project/docs ... is there a tutorial that you know of that I can configure for nginx so i can point the sphinx data to? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

There are some good use cases for integrating sphinx doc into Django:

- Allow for dynamic content within documentation (i.e. user login, current time, etc).
- Integrate the documentation with your overall sitemap.
- Only one set of templates / CSS files to create and maintain.

If you have one or more of these needs, I would take a look at [django-sphinxdoc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinxdoc), it handles all basic use cases out of the box but can be easily modified.

Comment: I did. django-sphinxdoc  would have been perfect except that i was working with an old django project. Incompatible with some of the django-sphinxdoc dependencies. Symlinking worked very well. I hooked it up to the admin interface. The clients were very happy :)