# Connect Django .html from urls.py

Tags: python, django

I would like to be able to click in a tab and directly access to a specific view template.

I tried using TemplateView as suggested here: [Django urls straight to html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402708/django-urls-straight-to-html-template)
But is not working for me.

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.views import *
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'culturesView.html'), name = 'culturesView'),
    path('<str:sample_id>/culturesView/', views.culturesView, name='culturesView'),
    path('addSample/', views.addSample, name='addSample'),
]
```

The idea is to be able to connect directly to /main/culturesView.html
It worked when I added this in my urls.py:

```
path('/main/culturesView.html', views.culturesView, name='culturesView')
```

However, If I want to access to this template again from already /main/culturesView.html
It will try to access to /main/main/culturesView.html

And it will keep adding the (main) in the path...

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why show things like `filename.html` in your url anyway? It doesn't look particularly good.

Comment: Because I dont know any other way to be able to access to the filename.html than writing this in the urls..

Comment: @AliciaPliego, change the name of the url path.